# Change the text color of an ElevatedButton in Flutter with ButtonStyle

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want a button that:

- Changes its background color based on whether it's in the pressed, disabled or normal state
- Changes its text color depending on whether it's in the disabled or normal state

I'm trying to achieve this with the ButtonStyle class.

```
ElevatedButton(
  child: Text("Example"),
  onPressed: onPressed, // onPressed is a function
  style: ButtonStyle(
    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) { return KPColors.offWhite; }
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) { return KPColors.primaryLight; }
      return KPColors.primaryExtraLight;
    }),
    textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
      Color textColor = states.contains(MaterialState.disabled) ? KPColors.gray : KPColors.primary;
      return TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: textColor);
    }),
    overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(KPColors.clear), // prevents the shimmer effect when pressing the button
    shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16))), // Rounds the corners
    elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(0), // Prevents shadow around button
  ),
),
```

The code succeeds in changing the background color of the button, but not the text color, which appears white instead of my custom color. I think this is because ElevatedButton's child is a Text widget, which has a default text color which is overriding mine.

How can I solve this? I already know that I can change the text color of the button by using ElevatedButton.styleFrom(...) and setting the onPrimary property, instead of ButtonStyle, but this would make it much more difficult to have different colors depending on the pressed and disabled states of the button.

Comment: Haven't you tried to add color argument to your `Text` widget instead of putting it in `ButtonStyle`?

Comment: How would I make it responsive to whether the button state is enabled or disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set the `foregroundColor` in the `ButtonStyle`

For example:

```dart
foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) { return Colors.grey; }
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) { return Colors.green; }
      return Colors.blue;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ElevatedButton.styleFrom`

```
ElevatedButton(
  child: Text("Example",style:TextStyle(color:isActive ? Colors.white : Colors.black)),
  onPressed: isActive ? (){print('do somthing');} : (){}, // onPressed is a function
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: isActive ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey),
        )
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).